# why `float` declaration is like this `public struct Single`

Tags: c#, .net

i was checking the data types in C# and I saw float is actually named as `Single` i didn't understand it as the other data types like `int` `char` `decimal` etc have an appropriate name but  `float` is like `Single` why is that?

Comment: It's "Single" precision in contrast to "Double" precision. Thatswhy `double` is `System.Double` and `float` is `System.Single`.

Comment: How is it not "appropriate"? `Single` == single-precision IEEE754 floating-point, `Double` == double-precision IEEE754 floating-point. Are you asking why it isn't `Float`? or are you asking why the keyword isn't `single`? - if the latter: see C

Comment: Because you have `Single` (4 byte) and `Double` (8 byte) floating point numbers. The `float` and `double` names come from the ancient C/C++

Comment: Also note that `int` is `public struct Int32`, `long` is `public struct Int64` etc...

Comment: No guidance to be found when choosing either `float` or `Single`... any ideas when to use either or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with decimal numbers lingo.

Float is an implementation of [Single precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). As a matter of fact `Double` gets its name because, well it has double the amount of bytes as a single (float) one.